# Javascript - Stop form submit depending on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm wanting to use AJAX to determine whether or not a form's values are acceptable to me (this is not form validation). The AJAX `result` will determine if the form is submitted or not.

Below, you'll see that I perform an AJAX call when the form is submitted and depending what is returned (either blank which is acceptable, or an error message which is not acceptable), I'd like to `return true;` or `return false;` the `$("form").submit`.

I suspect my trouble to be in the AJAX's `success:`. Please help me get the `result` out of the AJAX call so that I can do something like `if (result == "") { return true; } else { return false; }`.

WORKING:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    var tray = $('select[name=tray_id]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/reserve-check.php",
        data: {tray_id: tray},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(result) {
        if (result == "")
            form.submit();
        else
            alert(result);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('ERROR');
    });
});
```

ORIGINAL:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var tray = $('select[name=tray_id]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/reserve-check.php",
        data: {tray_id: tray},
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert(result); //This works as expected (blank if acceptable and error msg if not acceptable)
        }
    });

    /*
    if (result == "")
        return true; 
    else
        return false; 
    */
    return false; //this is here for debugging, just to stop the form submission
});
```

Comment: Why not just submit the whole form to the server with an AJAX call and let the server decide what is acceptable. Then you can have the server return a success or error code and you can act accordingly

Comment: You can only return from synchronous code, Ajax is asynchronous. Read the post above and work with callbacks.

Comment: Further to what Mike W said, if you do do a pre-submit acceptability test via Ajax you really need to repeat the test within the PHP code you then submit to, in case the user had JS disabled or otherwise managed to bypass your submit handler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the ajax call is asynchronous, you have to prevent the form from submitting, and then when a result is returned, you check if it matches the condition and submit the form with the native submit handler, avoiding the `preventDefault()` in the jQuery event handler :

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = this,
        tray = $('select[name=tray_id]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/reserve-check.php",
        data: {tray_id: tray},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(result) {
        if (result == "") self.submit();
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('error');
    });
});
```

Comment: and also `$("form").off('submit')` would be fine

Comment: @claustrofob - No it wouldn't. That doesn't cause a submit.

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right. It is a native DOM object.

Comment: If I use $("form").submit() instead of self.submit() the console shows that the ajax call runs forever! Could you please explain why this happens? By the way, thanks for the answer. +1

Comment: @hex494D49 - It happens because the jQuery event handler cathes the `submit` event. In other words, when you do `$("form")` you end up in the `$("form").submit(function() {...})` event handler, which in turns tries to submit the form again, ending up in the same event handler, which in turn trues to submit the form again, ending up in the same event handler ... and so on. When you call the **native** `form.submit()`, which isn't a jQuery function, the event handler isn't triggered, and the form is submitted.

Comment: @adeneo I've got it :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: brief and to the point!

Comment: @adeneo This is by far the most elegant solution to the callback hell! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 3):

use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from submitting, and then use `this.submit()` (isn't calling the jQuery `.submit()` trigger function, but rather the native `<form> .submit()` function) to submit the form.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var tray = $('select[name=tray_id]').val();
            var form = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "modules/reserve-check.php",
                data: {tray_id: tray},
                cache: false,
                complete : function(result){callback(result, form)}
            });       
        });

var callback = function(result, form){
  if(!result)
    form.submit();
};
```

Comment: This won't work. (Hint: what does the "A" in "Ajax" stand for?)

Comment: No way, again! Using `$(this).submit()` will just trigger the same event handler once more.

Comment: And now you have a scoping issue, as `this` inside the function calls in $.ajax is not the form.

Comment: it took me all this time! Should I go to bed? :D

Comment: You've almost finished. Dont give up!

Comment: It will work. But using global variables is a bad way. I would pass it as a parameter to callback `var callback = function(result, form)`

Comment: Of course, seems better now :D

Comment: it is funny but you missed a scope again. `function(result){callback(result, this)}` `this` refers to `ajax` object

Comment: haha your fault :D, thanks ;)

Comment: This answer seems very close to working, but it's going wrong at `if (result == "")` because result is `[object Object]`?!

Comment: Up vote for getting so close!

Comment: Thanks :D, you're probably right, he can use `if (!result )` to test if `result` is empty or not

Comment: Solved my problem expect if (result == "") is a object strugling from last 2 hour finally solved this, up vote for this help