# jquery - Post form to one URL with ajax then submit form to it's action

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form and want it so that when the user submits it, it does the following:

1. Posts the data to a URL with ajax.
2. Waits for the script at (1) to finish executing
3. Submits the form as normal (to it's URL in the `action` parameter).

I've read the following and am having a hard time making sense of it:

- [Javascript - Stop form submit depending on ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097245/javascript-stop-form-submit-depending-on-ajax-response)
- [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

This is what I have, and what I've tried:

```
<form id="contactUsForm" method="post" action="/email.php">

    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="sendBtn" value="Send">

</form>
```

So I began by stopping the form submitting as normal:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

This works.

I now want to post 2 fields (`firstName`, `lastName` to a script called `curl.php`) with ajax. I've added this:

```
var self = this,
    firstName = $('#firstName').val(),
    lastName = $('#lastName').val()

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/curl.php",
         data: {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName},
         cache: false
     }).done(function(result) {
         console.log(result);  
         self.submit();
      }).fail(function() {
         alert('error');
      });
```

My `curl.php` script contains the following - which just outputs the POST data for the 2 fields:

```
echo 'FirstName: ' . $_POST['firstName'] . '<br>';
echo 'LastName: ' . $_POST['lastName'] . '<br>';
```

I was expecting this would appear in my console, because `console.log(result)` should output the response from `curl.php`?

In the Network tab a request is made to `curl.php` but there is no response data. The form then submits as expected to `email.php`.

I'm unclear whether there's an issue with the way I'm making the ajax call, but am assuming `curl.php` isn't actually "finishing" before `email.php` is executed?

Please can someone give me some pointers on where I'm going wrong. I've spent a lot of time reading the above links and about Promises, but am seemingly unable to make sense of this!

I understand about ajax being asynchronous. But I don't know how to instruct it to "wait" until `curl.php` has finished executing before executing `email.php`.

Comment: Your logic looks fine. The console is probably empty due to the postback occurring. Did you enable preserve logs in your dev tools?

Comment: I did tick 'Preserve log'. It's giving me the output in the console (from `console.log(result);  `) but under Network > `curl.php` > Response, it says "failed to load response data". Why is this, given that the script (`curl.php`) is producing output?

Comment: I suggest checking you server log. I just set this up, as is, and I'm able to log the response from `curl.php`. I added `setTimeout(self.submit(), 8000);` to verify that the console prints `result`, which it does.

Comment: Something weird is happening for me. I added `setTimeout(self.submit(), 8000);` after `console.log(result)` but it's not delaying by 8 seconds - it submits straight away?? jquery version is 1.12.4. If I comment out `setTimeout(self.submit(), 8000);` (so the form doesn't submit at all) I see both the `console.log(result)` and the Response data in the Network tab.

Comment: I also tested it with jquery 3.2.1 to make sure it wasn't a version issue. Results are the same as 1.12.4