# Html form submit after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Trying to make some database validation with Jquery Get method before submitting a form. But I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function

Got the logic form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097245/javascript-stop-form-submit-depending-on-ajax-response/17097461#17097461)

Simplified Code below (but the err is still there...)

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="insertCertificateForm">
        <form action="/Certificates/Insert" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>Charge</label>
                <input name="Charge" id="Charge" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-default" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#insertCertificateForm').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = this;

            var Charge = $('#Charge').val();

            $.get("/Certificates/CheckIfChargeIsUnique", { Charge: Charge }, function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    form.submit();
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may be because form =this is not returning a form

Comment: do a console.log(form) to verify yourself

Comment: add use the **this** keyword where there is anonymity in detecting the event submitter...otherwise it creates confusion ...go for id Selector #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong `$('#insertCertificateForm')`, if you want to do like this you need to add this id into your form `<form id="insertCertificateForm"` otherwise follow this way,

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var Charge = $('#Charge').val();

    $.get("/Certificates/CheckIfChargeIsUnique", { Charge: Charge }, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $(this).submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because after clicking button **this** would mean *the current button* and

**insertCertificateForm** was never a form anyways...it was ***Div***

best would be to bind the form with an ID ***#myForm***

```
<html>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <div id="insertCertificateForm">
            <form  id="Myform" action="/Certificates/Insert" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label>Charge</label>
                    <input name="Charge" id="Charge" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-default" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('#insertCertificateForm').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $("#Myform");

                var Charge = $('#Charge').val();

                $.get("/Certificates/CheckIfChargeIsUnique", { Charge: Charge }, function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        form.submit();
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and also load your scripts in the head

Comment: Jesus.. 2h looking in to this and I had the Id on the wrong element the whole time... Thx!

Comment: I have spent days because of a  misplaced class name :( hence observation has improved with time

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're calling `this` and not `$(this)` when declaring the form variable. You can either declare it as `$(this)` or use `$(form)` to submit the form.